# ender 3 repeated power outage issue

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply

My ender 3 is repeatedly claiming there is a power outage at the exact same spot in a specific print over and over again. There obviously has been no power outage. The chord is very secure in the outlet, nothing else in the house has turned off or reset, and it happens in the exact same spot over and over again. I've run this print probably about 5 times now, and other prints in between as well. My other prints seem to work (I didn't really want them, so I stop them pretty early on, but long enough I feel confident those prints aren't having the same problem.)

It stops about a couple millimeters after the first circuit of the brim. It claims there was a power outage, and asks if I'd like to resume or quit the print. If I choose to resume, it does not resume from the same spot; it restarts the print from the beginning, makes one circuit of the brim and then dies in the exact same way.

What on earth is going on?

I'm trying to read through [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/why-is-my-ender-3-restarting-spontaneously-in-mid-print) answer. But I guess I don't know the anatomy of my printer well enough. All I understand is that he's saying a wire might be loose somewhere. I think he meant one of the wires from the power supply to the rest of the board (as he had already ruled out from the wall to the power supply).

However, I don't believe that's what's going on with me. If my problem were the same as his, I would expect that my print should start working again after slowing the print down to perhaps 25% of the default speed. But after testing this the problem persists. I believe the problem has to do with the gcode file itself, but I have no idea how to go about testing that hypothesis.

Comment: Gcode could be corrupted and crashing the printer, try reslicing on a new install of cura. You can also try formatting the SD card, or reflashing the firmware but I dont suspect this to be an issue

Comment: @F.Ahmed Thanks for the comment. I don't know why, but it's working again. Either, reslicing the gcode fixed the problem as you suggested, or increasing the layer width (though I have no idea why that would fix it; that's just the only other thing I changed). It's odd, because I resliced thrice with the same results, but I guess fourth time two weeks later was the charm?